# Stellent get_dynamic_page service not working

Tags: oracle, workflow, stellent

A power outage brought the server down over the weekend and after restarting Stellent the GET_DYNAMIC_PAGE service doesn't work. This is the first part of the error message I'm seeing:

```
Unable to retrieve page. Unable to execute service method 'getDynamicPage'. (System Error: Runtime error: java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:396)
```

Other IdcServices work such as WORK_IN_PROGRESS and GET_DOC_PAGE.

I'm also getting an error when trying to start the Web Layout Config, it says it can't launch executePageService -- since the files created by the Web Layout Config are the ones served by GET_DYNAMIC_PAGE I imagine there's a connection...

What's weird is that this is happening on the dev server -- the production server also went down but when it was started it ran fine. I've spent the last day and a half trying to discover what's different between the dev and prod servers and they appear to be identical.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening a ticket with Oracle we figured out the problem was caused by a mangled lockwait.dat file here: [StellentDir]\data\pages\

**To fix the problem:**

- Turn off the Stellent server
- Open the [StellentDir]\data\pages\ folder
- Delete the lockwait.dat and PageTree.map files
- Restart the Stellent server

According to Oracle those two files will be recreated, although in our case only the lockwait.dat file came back, but the lack of PageTree.map doesn't seem to be causing any problems, so we consider the issue fixed.

I had to reload the broken page twice, but after that it worked fine. For a few days, anyways, and then it stopped working again. Blowing away the lockwait.dat file fixes it, but Stellent no longer seems like the rock solid app it used to be. Maybe it's time we upgrade...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Content Server Logs, what does the full stack trace show?

Do you have any customizations on your system?

What version of WebCenter Content are you running (7.x, 11g, 12c)?

Comment: We're running 10gR3, there are some customizations, but nothing that happened anytime near when the problem started (they were done years before), and the stack trace follows:

`Event generated by user 'sysadmin' at host 'app32.foo.lan'. 
Unable to retrieve page. 
Unable to execute service method 'getDynamicPage'. (System Error: Runtime error: java.lang.NullPointerException 
at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:396) 
at intradoc.data.DataBinder.putLocal(DataBinder.java:1195) 
at intradoc.server.ServiceRequestImplementor.setStatusMessageEx(ServiceRequestImplementor.java:1718) `
...

Comment: It is probably wise to open an SR with Oracle.